# way for using DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) condition in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, sql-date-functions

i am using cakephp and creating this condition:

```
$conditions = array("Userword.levelid"=>0, "Userword.userid"=>$this->Auth->user('UserId'),"date(Userword.date)"=>"DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)");  
$Userword = $this->paginate(null, $conditions);
```

cake using this select :

```
`Userword`.`userwordid`, `Userword`.`userid`, `Userword`.`wordid`, `Userword`.`date`, `Userword`.`levelid`, `Word`.`wordid`, `Word`.`word`, `Word`.`meaning`, `User`.`UserId`, `User`.`Email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`cell`, `User`.`web` FROM `userwords` AS `Userword` LEFT JOIN `words` AS `Word` ON (`Userword`.`wordid` = `Word`.`wordid`) LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Userword`.`userid` = `User`.`UserId`) WHERE date(`Userword`.`date`) = 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)'
```

but by this select mysql can't return record because cakephp in this select use this character (`'`) in last passage.
when i remove this character and test this code in `phpmyadmin` this code return rows. two images in below show this :

[image: cakephp mysql code]

[image: image of phpmyadmin without <code>'</code> character]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just don't separate it out as key => value pair:

```
$conditions = array(
   ...
   'DATE(Userword.date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)'
);
```